# GWT DialogBox : Not able to click anywhere on the page apart from the dialog box

Tags: gwt, dialog

I am using a dialog box to show some information in my UI. That dialog box has a vertical panel inside it and the vertical panel has a textArea.

Now if we open the dialog box by clicking a button on my page, I am not able to click anywhere outside that dialog box.

Now the consequence of this :

1) I have a session timeout of 10 min after which I am logged out .

2) I have a session refresh event that triggers when we click anywhere on the root panel.

3) But once the dialog box is open, I am not able to click anywhere outside the dialog box which results in my session timing out.

I want something that would enable me to click on my page even when the dialog box is open. Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Adding dialogBox.setModal(false), I am able get this working.

One question though, when we have a large text in a HTML widget we get a scrollbar to scroll through, how can I add a eventHandler when we scroll through by clicking the scroll down/up arrow on that scrollbar ?

Comment: easiest way would be to put the html panel inside a ScrollPanel and add a scroll handler.

Comment: I tried this, but it creates 2 scroll bars ( One for the scroll panel and other for the HTML as it has huge text inside it).
I added a scroll handler to the scroll panel, but with that scroll I am not able to scroll through the text that is in HTML.

I want to generate a event when I am scrolling through the text inside HTML.